# Conversion de fechas en Genexus

Tags: genexus

por favor alguien que me ayude tengo este codigo en el cual estoy leyendo un archivo de excel en Genexus pero al leerle las fechas no me lee y no se me visualiza entonces me podrian porfavor ver como podría arreglarlo.Ya le intente ctod para la ocnversión pero aún asi no me sirve, alguien alguna idea.

&RDEP_XLS.Open("C:\Catastro\CLI.xls")

if &RDEP_XLS.ErrCode <> 0
&RDEP_XLS.Close()
else
&ExcelCuentaContrato  = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(4,3).Text
msg(&ExcelCuentaContrato)
&fila=4
&NumCuentaContrato=&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,3).Text
&Mensaje=''
Do While not &NumCuentaContrato.IsEmpty()
For each Cliente
where CliNumCuentaContrato=&NumCuentaContrato
when none
Do 'GrabaCliente'
EndFor

```
    &Cliente.Load(&NumCuentaContrato)
    
    &ClienteDeudas=new()
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasId=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,24).Text)
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago=CtoD(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Text) //no hace la conversión
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimaEmision.ToString(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,16).Text) //no hace la conversión
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasValorUltimaFactura=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,17).Text)
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaVencimientoUltimaFactura.ToString(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,76).Text) //no hace la conversión
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasPlanillasPendientes=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,23).Text)
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasMontoDeuda=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,24).Text)
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasMesesPendientes=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,86).Text)
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasEstadoDeReclamacion = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,53).Text
    &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasValorVencido=val(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,25).Text)
    
    &Cliente.Deudas.Add(&ClienteDeudas)
    
    &Cliente.Save()
    if &Cliente.Success()
    commit
else
    &Mensaje='Error' + &Cliente.CliNumCuentaContrato
EndIf

    &fila += 1
    &NumCuentaContrato=&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,3).Text
enddo
```

endif

Comment: No entendí si en la planilla ya tienes una fecha porque no usas .Date en lugar de .Text (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7036,Date+Property) 
Otra cosa que probaria es qué devuelve el .Text de esas columnas (en qué formato), de pronto lo puedes mover a una variable string primero y luego el CTOD sobre esa (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7472,CtoD%20function) eventualmente en la planilla está como DateTime y capaz sirce CtoT (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7473,CtoT%20function)

Comment: ¿De qué tipo son los elementos del SDT que intentas asignar (&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago, &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimaEmision y  &ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaVencimientoUltimaFactura)? ¿Qué valor tienes en el Excel en la fila &fila, columnas 15,16 y 76? Esto sería de gran ayuda para responder la pregunta.

Comment: Tienen un formato General en el excel

Answer (score 0):

¿Probaste obteníendola como .date en lugar de .text?

```
&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Date
```

En caso de que esto no funcione, podrías tomarla en una variable texto, ver en que formato lo toma y luego setearla.
Por ejemplo, tomas el texto y ves que te devuelve 05/14/2022 (formato Mes/Dia/Año)

```
&fechaEnTexto = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,15).Text
&dia = &fechaEnTexto.Substring(3,2)
&mes = &fechaEnTexto.Substring(1,2)
&ano = &fechaEnTexto.Substring(7,4)
&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimoPago.Set(&ano,&mes,&dia)
```

Veo que estás usando el **.ToString** en lugar del **.FromString.** En caso de venir en formato correcto sería:

```
&ClienteDeudas.CliDeudasFechaUltimaEmision.FromString(&RDEP_XLS.Cells(&fila,16).Text)
```